# PHP Paypal express 10413

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using Paypal Express Checkout on my website and i receive this error:

```
SetExpressCheckout API call failed. Detailed Error Message: The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.Short Error Message: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.Error Code: 10413Error Severity Code: Error
```

When i enter a quantity of 1 everything is working fine but when i enter 2 or more i get the error.

I'm using SMARTY Templating.

```
            <form class="pull-right" action="../Checkout/paypal_ec_redirect.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0" value="{$product_naam}"></input>
                <input type="hidden" name="L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0" value="{$product_productprijs}"></input>
                <input type="hidden" name="L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0" value="{$product_aantal}"></input>

                <input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT" value="{$product_subtotaal}"></input>
                <input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT" value="{$product_btw}"></input>
                <input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT" value="{$product_totaalprijs}"></input>
                <input type="hidden" name="currencyCodeType" value="EUR"></input>
                <input type="hidden" name="paymentType" value="Sale"></input>

                <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/buttons/checkout-logo-large.png" alt="Check out with PayPal"></input>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
foreach ($getproduct as $row) {
    $productaantal = $aantalbesteld;
    $productnaam = $row['naam'];
    $productprijs = $row['prijs'];
    $btwtarief = $row['btw_tarief'];
    $btwbedrag = ($productprijs*$aantalbesteld)/100*$btwtarief;
    $subtotaal = ($productprijs*$aantalbesteld)-$btwbedrag;
    $totaalprijs = $productprijs*$aantalbesteld;
}


//Product
$smarty->assign('product_naam', $productnaam);
$smarty->assign('product_aantal', $productaantal);
$smarty->assign('product_prijs', money_format('%.2n', $productprijs));
$smarty->assign('product_subtotaal', money_format('%.2n', $subtotaal));
$smarty->assign('product_btw', money_format('%.2n', $btwbedrag));
$smarty->assign('product_totaalprijs', money_format('%.2n', $totaalprijs));
$smarty->assign('product_bestelknop', 'Bestellen');
```

EDIT: Even this isn't working:

```
            <form class="pull-right" action="../Checkout/paypal_ec_redirect.php" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0" value="{$product_naam}"></input>
                <input type="hidden" name="L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0" value="5.00"></input>
                <input type="hidden" name="L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0" value="2"></input>

                <input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT" value="10.00"></input>
                <input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT" value="2.10"></input>
                <input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT" value="12.10"></input>
                <input type="hidden" name="currencyCodeType" value="EUR"></input>
                <input type="hidden" name="paymentType" value="Sale"></input>

                <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/buttons/checkout-logo-large.png" alt="Check out with PayPal"></input>
            </form>
```

Comment: can you post the complete response(with correlation id) ?

Comment: by the way, i can see lot of people upvoting to a question without any reason , weird

Comment: Hello Techycommerce, Thanks for your reply. What do you mean with the complete response? This is everything i get. I don't know why people are upvoting my question.

Comment: you said, SetExpressCheckout API call failed. It should fail with an error.
What all information you get along with the error?
you should see something like this
<pre><code>
TIMESTAMP=2015-03-31T09:33:37Z
CORRELATIONID=3fba31008cb2f
ACK=Failure
VERSION=80.0
BUILD=15840636
L_ERRORCODE0=10413
L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
L_LONGMESSAGE0=The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.
L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error

Comment: and someone upvoted your comment too !!! lol

Comment: hahaha unbelieveable..., ON TOPIC: I don't get that error. Please see my website here: http://goo.gl/5k7U5E When you change the "qty" in the link you 'll see the error.

Answer (score 0):

It says when they multiply quantity and amount it doesn't add up to what you specify as totalamount

```
$btwbedrag = ($productprijs*$aantalbesteld)/100*$btwtarief;
$subtotaal = ($productprijs*$aantalbesteld)-$btwbedrag;
$totaalprijs = $productprijs*$aantalbesteld;
```

Your VAT is calculated by taking 1% of the total price amount multiply by VAT rate. This assumes your product amounts are exclusive VAT.

Then in the next line you remove VAT from `$subtotaal`, why? It wasn't included in the first place. Or if it was then you should divide by 121 instead of 100.

`$totaalprijs` seems to be calculated assuming VAT is included already.

Did you check the values of your hidden fields in the source of your page?

Comment: Because the price includes 21% TAX. so what i do with subtotal is calculating the total price without the TAX. Please check my edited post above.

Answer (score 0):

When I changed the qty to `2`, this is the request that is sent to PayPal.

```
paymentrequest_0_currencycode   "EUR"
paymentrequest_0_amt    "89.90"
paymentrequest_0_itemamt    "71.02"
paymentrequest_0_taxamt "18.88"
paymentrequest_0_paymentaction  "Sale"
paymentrequest_0_name   "Sweaters van Superdry"
paymentrequest_0_qty    "2"
```

Ideally, the request should be like this:

```
paymentrequest_0_itemamt=71.02
paymentrequest_0_taxamt=18.88
paymentrequest_0_amt=89.90


L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0 = Sweaters van Superdry
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0= 35.51  
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0= 2
```

This is causing the problem.

There is no `paymentrequest_0_qty` parameter.

You can test it here :

https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?&user=us-30_api1.cri.com&pwd=EYFNSNUSV85CT34Z&signature=AH57zE.nAaElaFFAysViNA9TIte1AxtSpBjx2HLqHJOiu2js3l1Kd48i&version=70.0&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&RETURNURL=http://www.paypal.com/test.php&CANCELURL=http://www.paypal.com/test.php&PAYMENTACTION=Sale&paymentrequest_0_itemamt=71.02&paymentrequest_0_taxamt=18.88&paymentrequest_0_amt=89.90&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Sweateranuperdry&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=35.51&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=2

Just click/copy-pasate the link above and see the reponse

Comment: I thought that "paymentrequest_0_itemamt" was the total price of the products excluding VAT. Doesn't work yet :(, Changed the code on the website.

Comment: Still get the error and i did everything you said. You can see it here: http://bakkers.work/paypalinselem.PNG

Comment: Something is wrong when you post the api request to PayPal,  try to print the request before sending to PayPal and check